# Shift + Alt consumes triple-key combinations

Tags: 13.10

I've got <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> for keyboard layout change. But it forbids me to use combination like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Very often used in Eclipse/Java). When I press these 3 keys the language is changed and Eclipse cannot intercept the key press. That happened after the upgrade to **13.10**.
Is there some fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of work being done about this issues. Layout change was really broken by the upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10, and although most of it has been fixed, there are still problems.

The general bug with links to all the others is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322

There is an issue similar to the one you mentioned with  Ctrl+Shift here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246656

Reading https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322/comments/407 seems that your problema can be fixed by adding the experimental PPA from attente. But there are conflicting reports around.

If you need help to add a PPA see https://askubuntu.com/a/40351/16395

Comment: Thanks but now I'm too afraid to apply patches on my system cause of the risk to cripple it.

Comment: I used the PPA from attente and it gave no problem to me (and you can remove it with `purge-ppa` if you change your mind). But yes, it's a bit risky nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu **System Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Typing** and change the ***Switch to next source*** shortcut to something else or disable at all if you aren't using it.

Comment: Problem is I'm accustomed from lots of years to both of these combinations and I don't want to change any of them.