# Alt+Shift layout switching problem in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I tried to set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as the keys to switching a keyboard layout in my **Ubuntu 13.10**.

The only problem is every time I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> when I set the keys, it is also writing "Next Group".

When I try to switch layouts, it doesn't work. What is this "Next Group" key and what I did wrong?

[image: http://postimg.org/image/koj1poh3d/]

I also tried:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle en,he
```

but I got this error:

```
Error loading new keyboard description
```

**My question is what is this "Next Group" key and why is it showing when I don't press any other key, and not how to use shift_alt to change keyboard layout.**

Comment: Try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/407497/cannot-change-keyboard-layout-after-uninstalling-unity/407740#407740

Comment: You can post your image e.g. [here](http://postimage.org/)

Comment: @Sneetsher I have tweak tools, it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Well know, long and difficult bug. See links at http://askubuntu.com/a/402303/16395

Comment: @Toalp, Did you try `setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle en,he`

Comment: @Sneetsher I did, but I got the error shown in the edit.